# Command tool to create torrent files that includes MD5 hashes of files?

Tags: command-line, bittorrent

I'm aware of mktorrent, and know how to use it, but for testing purposes I require a utility that will also include the MD5 hash of every file in the torrent in the torrent meta info.  I realize that the MD5 hash for each file isn't typically used with most modern torrent apps and is superfluous, but I'm hoping there's a utility out there I missed that supports this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this one: https://py3createtorrent.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

But you need to have python installed for this one .

"py3createtorrent is a comprehensive shell/commandline utility for creating torrents (Linux & Windows). It's a GPL-licensed Python v3.1 script. I tested it with Ubuntu 8.04 / rTorrent and Windows 7 / µTorrent."

Comment: FYI: As of py3createtorrent 0.9.5 the MD5 hashes need to be requested explicitly by providing the `--md5` switch. This makes the torrent creation much faster in the default case. (https://bitbucket.org/rsnitsch/py3createtorrent/commits/af745c8581deeeb1dabc1d3dd3413e19f480a68e)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `--checksum md5` option with torrenttools.

Other then MD5 various other hash functions are supported. You can list the available options with `torrenttools --checksum-algorithms`.

Torrenttools can be found here: https://github.com/fbdtemme/torrenttools

Disclaimer: I am the author of this tool.